# Django file save location

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new to using Django and I am trying to develop a website where the user is able to download a report file, these files are then stored in a folder static/doc/location.txt.

I have in management/commands

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
import json
import os
```

## Print the report

```
def service_area_by_region_top_category_count(self, services_in_service_area_by_region, region_name, limit):
    print('#### ' + region_name + ':')
    data_folder = "static\\location\\"
    file_to_open = data_folder + "location.txt" 
    with open(file_to_open, "a") as file_prime:
     file_prime.write(str('#### ' + region_name + ':')+ '\n')
    region_queryset = services_in_service_area_by_region[region_name]
    data_folder = "static\\location\\"
    file_to_open = data_folder + "location.txt" 
    with open(file_to_open, "a") as file_prime:
     for category in Category.objects.all().annotate(
        service_count=Count(Case(
            When(services__in=region_queryset, then=1),
            output_field=IntegerField(),
        ))
    ).order_by('-service_count')[:limit]:
          print(" - " + category.name + ": " + str(category.service_count))
          file_prime.write(str(" - " + category.name + ": " + str(category.service_count))+ '\n')
```

Everything working well but the file instead to be saved on the path static/doc/location.txt is saved on the root of the site with the name (static\location\location.txt).

[txt file created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLMEw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
data_folder = BASE_DIR + "my path"
```

Comment: I recive the same error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/location/location.txt'"!! Any idea? thank you very much

Comment: can you print the result of data_folder

Comment: BASE_DIR gives you the location of manage.py, make sure that your path is correct

Answer (score 0):

The static location in the settings.py file should be mentioned where you want to store. If you mention it there it will work.